# android sqlite error

Tags: android, sqlite

hi to all im using android with sqlite

and i got this error can any one tell me what it means please

```
05-01 11:24:00.972: INFO/Database(13623): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "=": syntax error
```

Comment: THe error means exactly what it says -- you have an error in your sqlite syntax near the = sign. Include the query so we can debug further ...

Answer (score 0):

Guess you miss the sign ?. Try **msg = ?**